# Как одновременно запустить асинхронный telethon и aiogram?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, бот, aiogram, telethon

Всех приветствую! Как можно сделать так, что бы асинхронные функции срабатывали как для aiogram, так и для telethon?

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channels))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if event.message.video:
        random_string = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k = 15))
        os.mkdir('videos/'+random_string)

        video_path = str(str(os.getcwd())+'/videos/'+random_string+'/').replace('\\','/')
        await client.download_media(event.media, video_path)

        file = os.listdir(video_path)
        random_id = int(admins_id_list[random.randint(0, len(admins_id_list) - 1)])
        await bot.send_video(random_id, open(video_path+file[0], 'rb'))


        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Да", callback_data='video_add_'+str(event.message.video.id)))
        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Нет", callback_data='video_remove_'))
        await bot.send_message(random_id, event.message.message+'\n\nЗанести видео в канал?', reply_markup=markup)





@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda event: event.data.startswith('video_add_'))
async def video_adder(event: types.callback_query.CallbackQuery):
    event_message = str(event.data).replace('video_add_','')
    print(event_message)







if __name__ == "__main__":
    client.start()
    client.run_until_disconnected()
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

После включение скрипта, запускается только telethon. (Ну или только aiogram, если поставить его запуск выше, чем telethon). Помогите пожалуйста, а то по ботам в интернете очень мало информации :/

Comment: Ну я думаю никак, хотя все возможно :)  А Зачем? Можно попробовать сделать два разных проекта под aiogram и telephon на один токен, и то хз как это будет работать.

Comment: Так telethon используют один способ авторизации, а aiogram другой. Или можно как-то через telethon создать бота, токен которого будет получен через BotFather?

Comment: https://git.groosha.space/-/snippets/8 в общем возможно вы такое уже находили, но мне кажется это именно тот алгоритм запуска и aiogram и telethon одновременно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Господи.. Решением оказалось обычное удаление строки: client.run_until_disconnected()
Я её тупо скопировал с примера telethon, не зная за что она отвечает... Целую неделю мучился :/